# Adding more vertical space between text and a tabbing environment

Tags: spacing, tabbing

I have choices typeset in a `tabbing` environment for a multiple-choice test that require more inter-line spacing. I use `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]` to separate the rows. Preceding the `tabbing` environment, I need a little more than the default inter-line spacing.  I tried using `\\[\normalbaselineskip]` but got more space than I got using `\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]` to separate rows in the `tabbing` environment.  What command should I use to give a proper inter-line spacing?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\noindent \textbf{92.) }If \textit{f} is a function such that $f^{\prime}(x) = -f(x)$, which of the following is equal to $\int x f(x) \, \mathit{dx}$? \\ [\normalbaselineskip]
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$(x + 1)f(x) + C$               \> \textbf{b.) }$-(x + 1)f(x) + C$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\> \textbf{c.) }$\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x) + C$  \> \textbf{d.) }$-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x) + C$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\> \textbf{e.) }$-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3}\right) + C$
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps replacing `\\[\normalbaselineskip]` (???) with `\bigskip`…  But your code is so… ahem! …strange.

Comment: To begin with, you don’t need `\usepackage{amsmath}` with the `amsart` document class.

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph (such as before tabbing)

Comment: @David Carlisle Would you use `\backslash \backslash` at the end of a paragraph?  In this case, the user wants to skip a line to start a row of choices.  Is this a different situation because the choices are in a tabbing environment?

Comment: @user143462 no _never_ use `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph it makes an underfull hbox of badness 10000 (which is the maximum value of TeX's badness measure) and awful spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the numbering and formatting to LaTeX. This also has the advantage that you can `\label` the items and later `\ref`erence them. The code below defines an environment `tabbedenum` to be used as follows.

```
\begin{tabbedenum}[optional indentation]{number of columns}
\item ...
\item ...
...
\end{tabbedenum}
```

This will generate a list numbered by letters arranged in several columns. The optional indentation, by default `0pt`, allows you to indent the complete multi-column list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[2][0pt]%
   {\medskip\par\noindent
    \advance\linewidth-#1
    \advance\leftmargin#1
    \parshape1\leftmargin\linewidth
    \NumTabs{#2}%
    \begin{inparaenum}%
    \renewcommand\labelenumii{\textbf{\theenumii)}}%
    \let\olditem\item
    \let\TAB\relax
    \def\item{\TAB\let\TAB\tab\olditem}%
    \ignorespaces
   }%
   {\par
    \end{inparaenum}%
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf{\theenumi.)}}%
\setcounter{enumi}{91}%
\item If $f$ is a function such that $f^{\prime}(x) = -f(x)$, which of
  the following is equal to $\int x f(x) \, \mathit{dx}$?
  \begin{tabbedenum}[1em]{2}
  \item $(x + 1)f(x) + C$
  \item $-(x + 1)f(x) + C$
  \item $\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x) + C$
  \item $-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x) + C$
  \item $-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2} \, f(x)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3}\right) + C$
  \end{tabbedenum}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you indent the first column of choices?

Comment: @user74973 I have added an optional argument to `tabbedenum` for indenting it, see above.

Comment: Is that `\medskip\par\noindent`?  If it is, can I have `\medskip\medskip\par\noindent`.  I would want the indentation to be more - half as much more to twice as much.

Comment: @user74973 No, it is the optional argument to `tabbedenum`, which is `1em` in my code above. Try `1.5em` or `2em` instead. `\medskip` is the vertical space before a)b)c)... If you want to change it, you can try `\bigskip` or `\vskip{...some length...}`.

Comment: @user74973 I've modified the code a bit and have added an explanation.

Comment: OK.  I could replace `1em` with either `1.5em` or `2em`.